# Enable and disable button

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm

I have a texbox in binding with a property.

```
 <TextBox Name="txtPrice"   Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="2" MaxLength="8" TabIndex="1"
   Text="{Binding Price, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, 
   StringFormat= '\{0:#,###.##\}', ConverterCulture=fr-FR}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>


      Private Property _Price As Double
        Public Property Price As Double
        Get
            Return Price
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _Price = Double.Parse(value)
            OnPropertyChanged("Price")
        End Set
    End Property
```

When I type some chars or the textbox is empty, the button **Cmd_Insert** must not be enabled, but doesn't work. 
Why ? (see Function **CanCmd_Insert**())

```
    Public ReadOnly Property Cmd_Insert As ICommand
    Get
        If _Cm_Insert Is Nothing Then
            _Cm_Insert = New RelayCommand(AddressOf Cmd_InsertExe, AddressOf CanCmd_Insert)
        End If
        Return _Cm_Insert
    End Get
End Property
Private Sub Cmd_InsertExe()
    UPDATE_Price()
End Sub
Private Function CanCmd_Insert() As Boolean
    If IsNumeric(Price) = False Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364364/mvvm-relaycommand-canexecute
 Its in C#

Comment: Try to set `Mode=TwoWay` in your binding

Comment: I have done, but doens't work ...

Comment: This is the issue. 
If I type a number, and after I delete it with backspace, the property **Price** has old value and the button is enabled yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `TargetNullValue=''` and changed your property to nullable. Refer the below code.

```
  <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Name="txtPrice"   Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="2" MaxLength="8" TabIndex="1"
   Text="{Binding Price, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue='',
   StringFormat= '\{0:#,###.##\}'}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />            
            <Button Content="Update" Command="{Binding Cmd_Insert }"></Button>
        </StackPanel>

    Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Private Property _Price As Double?
    Public Property Price As Double?
        Get
            Return _Price
        End Get
        Set(value As Double?)
            _Price = value
            OnPropertyChanged("Price")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub
    Private Property _Cm_Insert As ICommand
    Public ReadOnly Property Cmd_Insert As ICommand
        Get
            If _Cm_Insert Is Nothing Then
                _Cm_Insert = New RelayCommand(AddressOf Cmd_InsertExe, AddressOf CanCmd_Insert)
            End If
            Return _Cm_Insert
        End Get
    End Property
    Private Sub Cmd_InsertExe()

    End Sub
    Private Function CanCmd_Insert() As Boolean
        If IsNumeric(Price) = False Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Sorry .. but where is the TargetNullValue ? I didn't found

Comment: Edited my answer. Its in binding.