# MVVM-Light - RelayCommand CantExecute issue

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I have a problem with MVVM-Light. I use the version 5.3.0.0...

**.XAML**

```
<DockPanel Dock="Top">
        <Button Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding CancelDownloadCommand}" FontSize="20" 
                Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush4}" ToolTip="Cancelar"
                DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Images/48x48/Error.png" Height="48" Width="48"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding ToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}" FontSize="20" 
                Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush4}" ToolTip="Descargar"
                DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Images/48x48/Download.png" Height="48" Width="48"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding ToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </DockPanel>
```

**DownloadViewModel.cs**

I used a MessageBox, but in my case, call a method that reads an XML. This example does not work, the buttons are disabled, but are not reactivated at the end of execution. I need to click on the UI to activate.

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;

private async void Download()
{
    Reset();

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    });

    Reset();
}

private void Reset()
{
    IsEnabled = !IsEnabled;
    IsEnabledCancel = !IsEnabledCancel;
}

private ICommand _downloadCommand;
public ICommand DownloadCommand
{
    get { return _downloadCommand ?? (_downloadCommand = new RelayCommand(Download, () => IsEnabled)); }
}

private ICommand _cancelDownloadCommand;
public ICommand CancelDownloadCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _cancelDownloadCommand ??
               (_cancelDownloadCommand = new RelayCommand(CancelDownload, () => IsEnabledCancel));
    }
}

private bool _isEnabled = true;
private bool IsEnabled
{
    get { return _isEnabled; }
    set
    {
        if (_isEnabled != value)
        {
            _isEnabled = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

private bool _isEnabledCancel;
private bool IsEnabledCancel
{
    get { return _isEnabledCancel; }
    set
    {
        if (_isEnabledCancel != value)
        {
            _isEnabledCancel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

By using **CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()**, I fixed it. But read somewhere that is not recommended because this command checks all RelayCommand. This did not happen to me before.

But if within the Task.Run not add anything. It works perfectly. Buttons are activated and deactivated again.

```
private async void Download()
{
    Reset();

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // WIDTHOUT CODE
        // WIDTHOUT CODE
        // WIDTHOUT CODE
    });

    Reset();
}
```

Comment: See also [MVVM RelayCommand CanExecute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19364364/774575) and the bug explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33149910/774575)

Answer (score 1):

When you update `CanExecute`, in your case `IsEnabled` and `IsEnabledCancel` properties, you have to raise `CanExecuteChanged` event.

Even more you can little bit simplify your code.

```
private bool _isEnabled;

public bool IsEnabled
{
    get { return _isEnabled; }
    set
    {
        if (Set(ref _isEnabled, value))
        {
            DownloadCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The same way update your `IsEnabledCancel` property.

Of course, you have to declare your command as `RelayCommand` and not `ICommand`.

```
private RelayCommand _downloadCommand;

public RelayCommand DownloadCommand
{
    get { return _downloadCommand ?? (_downloadCommand = new RelayCommand(Download, () => IsEnabled)); }
}
```

You can also read about: "[A smart MVVM command](http://www.mutzl.com/2014/02/a-smart-mvvm-command/)".

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code for MVVM Light](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight), it is based around the `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` (anti) pattern. Which you rightly say is a massive performance hog, due to the global nature of the (anti)pattern.

The problem lies in the constructor. `public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)`

With the `canExecute` being a `Func<bool>`, it is impossible to be able to get (at runtime) the property name, and is therefore impossible to bind on the the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event. Thus causing the command to re-evaluate the `canExecute`.

@kubakista shows you how to force the re-evaluation by calling the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method. But that really breaks the single responsibility principle, and leaks the implementation of the `ICommand`.

My advice is to use `ReactiveUI`'s `ReactiveCommand`. This allows you to do:

```
DownloadCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(Download, this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.IsEnabled).Select(enabled => enabled));
CancelDownloadCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(CancelDownload, this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.IsEnabled).Select(enabled => false == enabled));


public bool IsEnabled
{ 
    get {return _isEnabled; } 
    set
    {
        _isEnabled = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing i did notice is that your `Enabled` Properties (IsEnabled, IsEnabledCancel) are `private` when they should be `public`. However that doesn't fix your issue :)

A simple fix is to get rid of the `CanExecute` part of your Command
eg

```
public ICommand DownloadCommand
{
    get { return _downloadCommand ?? (_downloadCommand = new RelayCommand(Download)); }
}
```

and bind to your property on the `Button.IsEnabled`property in xaml
eg

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top"   
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}" 
        FontSize="20" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="2" 
        BorderBrush="Red" ToolTip="Descargar" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
    ...
</Button>
```

Hope that helps